# In-call status bar pushing view out of bottom

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an iOS app in swift.

I am having a dynamic splash screen and then login page.

I used this tutorial to replace frames:
[iOS: Root Controller Navigation](https://medium.com/@stasost/ios-root-controller-navigation-3625eedbbff)

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
   ...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      addChildViewController(current)               // 1
      current.view.frame = view.bounds              // 2             
      view.addSubview(current.view)                 // 3
      current.didMove(toParentViewController: self) // 4
   }
}

func showLoginScreen() {

      let new = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())                               // 1
      addChildViewController(new)                    // 2
      new.view.frame = view.bounds                   // 3
      view.addSubview(new.view)                      // 4
      new.didMove(toParentViewController: self)      // 5
      current.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)  // 6
      current.view.removeFromSuperview()]            // 7
      current.removeFromParentViewController()       // 8
      current = new                                  // 9
   }
}
```

But the issue is that it doesn't obey in-call status bar. My view gets displayed out of the screen from bottom if in-call status bar is open before app is opened.

Comment: can you show an image of your problem ?

Comment: Sure, my view goes approx 40 pixel out of screen from bottom

Answer (score 0):

use this in your `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {() -> Void in
        var windowFrame: CGRect? = (self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.view?.frame
        if newStatusBarFrame.size.height > 20 {
            windowFrame?.origin.y = newStatusBarFrame.size.height - 20
            // old status bar frame is 20
        }
        else {
            windowFrame?.origin.y = 0.0
        }
        (self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.view?.frame = windowFrame!
    })
}
```

Comment: But, I dont use UITabBarController